# "Would", used for speculation or inference

Tags: modal-verbs

> ## Scene 1
>
> Katniss Everdeen: President Snow. What an honor.
>
> President Snow: My dear, I think we can make this so much simpler. If we agree not to lie to each other, what do you think?
>
> Katniss Everdeen: Yes, I think that **would** save time.
>
> President Snow: Sit down, please.
>
> ## Scene 2
>
> Johanna Mason: How do we know the wire's not gonna burn up?
>
> Beetee: Because I invented it. I assure you, it won't burn up.
>   [they all look at each other for a moment]
>
> Johanna Mason: Well, it's better than hunting them down.
>
> Katniss Everdeen: Yeah, why not? If it fails, no harm done anyway, right?
>
> Peeta Mellark: Alright, I say we try it.
>
> Finnick Odair: So what can we do to help?
>
> Beetee: Keep me alive for the next six hours. That **would** be extremely helpful.
>
> *--The Hunger Games: Catching Fire*

I think these two **would** are used for speculation or inference and no conditionals are implied here.

When used this way, is it a less definite form of **will**? PEU<sup>1</sup> and *Advanced Grammar in Use* say little on this particular usage of **would**.

Can you please elaborate on this?

<sup>1. PEU = Michael Swan's, *Practical English Usage*.</sup>

Comment: The woulds in the examples sound conditional to me. I have always got confused on knowing if a would in a sentence is conditional or not. What is the best way to know whether would in a sentence is conditional or would for probability/speculation/assumption etc? (Please note I am not talking about would as past of will or would used to show past habituals)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your instincts are on target: in these cases *would* is being used in the same sense as *will*, but also expresses some doubt. *That would be Y* said in response to some *X* can be read here more or less as *if X is true, then Y*.

In scene one, there's some doubt over whether or not they'll both tell the truth. Also, in American English, *would* often sounds a bit more polite than *will*, and this is (I presume) a formal conversation between Katniss and the President.

In scene two, the doubt is over whether Beetee will be kept alive. I'm not familiar with the program, so I can't tell if Beetee is being sarcastic or not here. If so, the sarcasm implies that the question was stupid or unnecessary.

In both scenes, the person using *would* (Katniss or Beetee) is the one having doubts, though not necessarily the only one.

Comment: Who would have the doubt? Katniss or the President? Beetee or the others? BTW, I don't think sarcasm is implied in these scenes.

Comment: Good question. The speaker of *would* expresses and possesses the doubt (Katniss and Beetee).

Comment: If **will** or **should** were used instead of **would**, would there be any nuance implied?

Comment: I know what you mean, but _will/should_ is supposed to used with _save time/be extremely helpful_ rather than _lie/keep me alive_. This is different. You might have misinterpreted my previous comment. @Esoteric Screen Name

Comment: Sorry, I did indeed misread it. *Will* expresses certainty or confidence, and *should* indicates greater doubt than *would*, though the speaker is still more sure than not of the effect.

Comment: **Will** expresses certainty or confidence of what? Conditions of _not lie/keep me alive_ **or** only its effect alone when the conditions are satisfied?

Comment: Ugh, sorry again, I'm not being explicit enough. I'd read the *will* case in both scenarios as expressing certainty in the effects (saving time/being helpful) only. *Should* would express doubt about whether or not the effects will happen if the conditions (not lying/being kept alive) are true. It's also possible to use *should* or *would* rhetorically, to wryly or sarcastically imply that the effects should be obvious or certain. Regardless of the construction used, both scenes carry an undercurrent of doubt about the conditions.

Comment: Half a year passed; now I see the merit of your answer. Thx! "Would" here is used to introduce the consequence or evaluation of a hypothetical plan.